# Low Search - How to search fields with Date fieldtypes

Tags: low-search

I would just like to know how Date fields are searched.

In order to do this, I want to know in what format should I search.

Do I search datetime as a timestamp? as a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date fields in Safecracker form](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/date-fields-in-safecracker-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When using the range filters*, Low Search will transform a given date for a date field to a UNIX timestamp, using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime), unless an integer is given; then a timestamp is assumed.

Most dates in EE are stored as UNIX timestamps, which are accurate to the second. When you enter a date without a time, 00:00:00 is assumed as time (standard strtotime behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Low Search automatically detect the date field. You should search the date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd (like 2012-01-01).

Comment: So I don't need to specify the time?