# Low Search - Is it possible to do a date range (or any range) search in Low Search where multiple ranges are passed?

Tags: low-search

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="range:birthday[]" id="birthday">
    <option value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-20 years')).';'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-18 years')) ;?>">18-20</option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-25 years')).';'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-21 years')) ;?>">21-25</option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 years')).';'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-26 years')) ;?>">26-30</option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-35 years')).';'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-31 years')) ;?>">31-35</option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-40 years')).';'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-36 years')) ;?>">36-40</option>
    <option value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-50 years')).';'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-41 years')) ;?>">41-50</option>
    <option value="<?php echo ';'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-50 years')) ;?>">50+</option>
</select>
```

If I choose only one item, it works. But if I choose more than one item, it returns empty result.

Is it possible to do a date range (or any range) search in Low Search where multiple ranges are passed?

Comment: Here you can find the related answer: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/date-fields-in-safecracker-form/11594#11594

Comment: I don't see anything in the link that can solve the problem with multiple select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your experiment says enough. No, the range syntax does not support multiple items as parameter values. So `range:field="10;20"` is supported, `range:field="10;20|30;40|50;60"` is not. Will make a note of it as a FR.